# What filesystem should I use for an external USB drive that works for Mac, Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, debian, filesystems, osx-lion

At home I have multiple operating systems, Linux (debian), Mac OS X Lion and Winders 7. I have a large USB drive that I want to use to backup/transport files. What filesystem should I use that will allow multiple OS's to read/write to it. It is a 500 GB USB drive using USB 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

FAT32 is your best option for read/write access from Windows, OS X and Linux with no third-party add-ons. Note that it won't support individual files larger than 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

The only universal FS (without additional software) is sadly FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 is the lowest common demoninator and is a virtual guarantee of compatibilty but you'd probably be interested to know that NTFS is possible,
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382,
http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifehack/how-to-read-and-write-ntfs-windows-partition-on-mac-os-x.html